# no adobe pdf found in add-ons of ie8 in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf

In Windows Server 2008 R2, I couldn't able to open pdf files in IE8. Observed that there is no add-ons for Acrobat in Tools->Manage Add-ons.
No Adobe acrobat is installed in the machine. But, I could able to open pdf files in Firefox 36.0.
Please let me know how to open pdf files in IE browser

Comment: This is not a [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question.

Comment: From MVC application, I'm trying to open files in browser itself. When I searched for this issue in google, I found that adobe add-in should be enabled. But that add-in is not found in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Adobe reader and I could able to see pdf files in IE. Chrome and Firefox has support for pdf files by default. So, pdf files open without installation of Adobe reader. But we need to install adobe reader explicitly to support IE.